# Switch loop and cases

Tags: c, file, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 2
struct customer
{
    int accno ;
    char name[30] ;
    float balance ;
}e,m;
struct trans
{
    int accno;
    char trans_type ;
    float amount ;
}e2,m1;
int main()
{
    int k,i,p;
    char another='y',n;
    FILE *fp,*fr,*tp;
    //fp=fopen("customer.exe","rb");
    //fr=fopen("transaction.exe","wb");
    while(1){
        printf("\t\tCustomer Transactions:\n");
        printf("\t\t*********************\n\n\n");
        printf("\t1: Add customer information:\n\n");
        printf("\t2: Add transaction information:\n\n");
        printf("\t3: List customer information:\n\n");
        printf("\t4: List transaction information:\n\n");
        printf("\t5: Perform transaction:\n\n");
        printf("\t0: Exit:\n\n\n");
        printf("your choice ");
        scanf("%d",&p);
        switch (p){

        case 1:
            fp=fopen("customer.exe","wb");
            while(another=='y')
            {
                printf("\nEnter account number,Enter name,Enter balance");
                scanf("%d %s %f",&e.accno,&e.name,&e.balance);
                fwrite(&e,sizeof(e),1,fp);
                printf("Enter another y/n?");
                scanf(" %c",&another);
            }
            fclose(fp);
            break;

        case 2:
            fr=fopen("transaction.exe","wb");
            while(another=='y'){
                printf("\nEnter account number,Enter transaction type(w/d),Enter Amount");
                scanf("%d %c %f",&e2.accno,&e2.trans_type,&e2.amount);
                fwrite(&e2,sizeof(e2),1,fr);
                printf("\n\nEnter another y/n?");
                scanf(" %c",&another);
            }
            fclose(fr);
            break;

        case 3:

            fp=fopen("customer.exe","rb");
            printf("all account holders are\n\n");
            while(fread(&e,sizeof(e),1,fp)==1){
                printf("%d %s %f\n\n",e.accno,e.name,e.balance);
            }
            fclose(fp);
            break;

        case 4:
            fr=fopen("transaction.exe","rb");
            printf("\n\nEnter account number\n\n");
            scanf("%d",&m1.accno);
            while(fread(&e2,sizeof(e2),1,fr)==1){
                printf("%d %c %f\n\n",e2.accno,e2.trans_type,e2.amount);
            }
            fclose(fr);
            break;

        case 0:
            exit(1);

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

hey guys,
so i am working on this problem and i got stuck inside switch loop
so whats happening is i can freely select any case only if i compile and run, but if i am inside any case especially 1 or 2,i cant go back to 1 or 2.

for example suppose i input p as 1 bingo i am in case 1, but now after case 1 executed and if i now input 2 nothing happened. stuck in while loop but crazy thing is ,i can still freely select other cases.(except 1/2)

Comment: Please ___properly___ indent your code. Machine (Compiler) can read and compile anything, but for humans, it needs to make a little _sense_ while reading a block of text as _code_. When asking question, there was a big orange __How to Format__ box to the right of the text area. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a __[?]__ button giving formatting help. And a preview area  showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Indent your code please!

Comment: Strange data file names you  use ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are exiting the `case-1` you are inputting `another` to be `'n'`. Then you never reset it before you again consider the switch cases. That's the problem.

Inside the `while(1)` block - at the beginning make a assignment `another = 'y'`. That will basically make the condition on the two `while` loops to be true.

```
    while(1){
    ...

    another = 'y';  <---- 
    scanf("%d",&p);
    switch (p){

    case 1:
        fp=fopen("customer.exe","wb");
        while(another=='y')
        {
```

This will make your code enter the `while` block in those `case-1` or `case-2`.

---

- Apart from all these a general advise: check the return value of the functions used - for example `scanf`,`fopen` etc. It will save you from error cases that might occur due to failure of those functions.
- And compile your code with warnings enabled. `gcc -Wall -Werror progname.c`.
- You should limit the input of `scanf` when taking character string as input. For example it is recommended to use (As you know there will be 30 characters in the `name` including the `\0`).

  ```
  if( scanf("%29s",e.name) != 1){
     fprintf(stderr,"Error in input using scanf\n");
     exit(1);
  }
  ```

Comment: @kanishktanwar.: You understood the issue you had? ( I mentioned it in my answer)

Comment: Ya and I feel so dumb, thanks fr help been stuck there for hours, that's why I did not make it clearer

Comment: @kanishktanwar.: Glad to know...all the best.

Comment: @kanishktanwar if you had used your debugger to step through and inspect var values like 'another', you would have been stuck there for a couple minutes.

Comment: I am still learning programming, and I still need to learn how debuggers work

Comment: @MartinJames.: Yes that's right. Using `gdb` and setting a break point solves the issue momentarily. I guess OP is not aware of debugger now.